# WordPress theme upload fails with an error on AWS LightSail

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

[image: The link you followed has expired WordPress error]

I am getting the error "The link you followed has expired" when I try to upload the zip file of a theme. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmmm. Can you upload the theme's zip file using SFTP to bypass the problem?

Might be quicker than figuring out what's going on there...